# Custom role capabilities to administrator not taking effect (no plugin)

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, capabilities

I have created a custom post type from a plugin. I added a capability type `teacher`. Then I have added custom capabilities to administrator. But the problem is for the first time after completing this code it adds mentioned capabilities to the role. But when I change it further, it doesn't take effect. Like if I now delete the function `roles_to_edit_teacher`, still administrator will have the capabilities. So how to solve this issue?

```
function plugin_main_functions(){
register_post_type('teachers', array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name'=>__('Teachers List', 'Teachers'),
        'add_new' => __('add new teacher', 'Teachers'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add new teacher', 'Teachers')
        ),
    'public' => true,
    'supports'=> array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-groups',
    'capability_type' => array('teacher','teachers'),
    'map_meta_cap' => true

    ));

}
add_action('init','plugin_main_functions');

function roles_to_edit_teacher(){

    $admin = get_role('administrator');


    $admin->add_cap('edit_teacher');
    $admin->add_cap('edit_teachers');
    $admin->add_cap('read_teacher');
    $admin->add_cap('delete_teacher');
    $admin->add_cap('delete_teachers');
    $admin->add_cap('publish_teacher');
    $admin->add_cap('create_teachers');
}
add_action('init', 'roles_to_edit_teacher');
```

Answer (score 3):

Capabilities are stored in database, that is why they keep active even if you remove your function. Capabilities need to be expressly removed:

```
$admin  = get_role('author');
$admin->remove_cap( 'edit_teacher' );
```

And, because they are stored in database, you should stop adding them in every page load (as you are doing in `init` event). Usually, you should add custom capabilities on plugin activation hook and remove them on plugin deactivation:

```
add_action('init','plugin_main_functions');
function plugin_main_functions(){
  register_post_type('teachers', array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name'=>__('Teachers List', 'Teachers'),
        'add_new' => __('add new teacher', 'Teachers'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add new teacher', 'Teachers')
        ),
    'public' => true,
    'supports'=> array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-groups',
    'capability_type' => array('teacher','teachers'),
    'map_meta_cap' => true

  ));

}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, function () {

    // Call function plugin_main_functions(),
    // The function where the custom post type is registered
    plugin_main_functions();

    $admin = get_role('administrator');

    $admin->add_cap('edit_teacher');
    $admin->add_cap('edit_teachers');
    $admin->add_cap('read_teacher');
    $admin->add_cap('delete_teacher');
    $admin->add_cap('delete_teachers');
    $admin->add_cap('publish_teacher');
    $admin->add_cap('create_teachers');

    flush_rewrite_rules();

} );

register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, function () {

    // Call function plugin_main_functions(),
    // The function where the custom post type is registered
    plugin_main_functions();

    $admin = get_role('administrator');

    $admin->remove_cap('edit_teacher');
    $admin->remove_cap('edit_teachers');
    $admin->remove_cap('read_teacher');
    $admin->remove_cap('delete_teacher');
    $admin->remove_cap('delete_teachers');
    $admin->remove_cap('publish_teacher');
    $admin->remove_cap('create_teachers');

    flush_rewrite_rules();

} );
```

Then, if you need to modify the capabilities in a different event while the plugin is activate, you should do some checks before adding/removing capabilities so you don't perfrom unnecessary database operations.

For example:

```
add_action('init','plugin_main_functions');
function roles_to_edit_teacher(){
    if( $i_neet_to_remove_cap === true ) {
        $admin = get_role('administrator');
        $admin->remove_cap('some_capability');
    }
    if( $i_neet_to_add_cap === true ) {
        $admin = get_role('administrator');
        $admin->add_cap('some_capability');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks #cybmeta , But I have already stored capabilities in the database by adding my code... and now modified it with your code.. but still it is working as like as before... may be I need to clear the database...

Any Idea how to clear the database...

Comment: With my code you need to deactivate the plugin and reactivate again. Note that capabilities are being added on activation/deactivation hook. Have done it?

Comment: Yes, I have tried deactivating the plugin and then reactivate... but it doesn't work.... whatever I do with the code it just stays the same as before.

Comment: The code is working here and it is almost the same I use in several websites; your problem must be some where else, not in this code.